# How do you prevent a brute force log in attempt with Json Web Token and PHP

Tags: php, json, authentication, jwt

With sessions you can easily monitor and track  how many times a user tries and fails to log in, and when the number of failure is higher than a certain number, you just kick it request off, in order to prevent a hacker to query the database too many times and to gess the credentials.
Is there any strategy available to monitor user log-in attempts using pure Jason web token approach?

The only solution I managed to find so far is to use session for the log-in page and when the user is logged in I just use JWT for each request. Because user log-in once in few weeks, thanks to jwt, the server overload should be small, I presume. What do you think about this strategy?

Comment: I know that I can use captcha, the IP adress e the session. What I am interested to know is if there is a way to use jwt that allows me to monitor how many times a user tried to log in. For example i could use a jwt token for a failed log in and monitor the log in with that token, but it can be easily deleted.

Comment: That should be an edit to the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing brute forcing on forms can be done in multiple ways. Some common methods are:

- Using a captcha
- Logging the IP address and amount of login attempts
- Logging login attempts using sessions

#### Captcha

A captcha is a good method to prevent brute forcing. However, visitors might find this annoying. Google's new captcha places a button below your login script. This button says: 'I am not a rabot'. By the way in which you click this button, google can determine if you are human or not. I find this to be the best method.

#### Logging the IP

You see this method being used on alot of fora. You'll have to wait 15 minutes after 5 failed login attempts. This prevents users from trying multiple logins.

#### Session logging

This works the same as the IP logging, however session can easily be manipulated.

#### Resources

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798918/what-is-the-best-method-to-prevent-a-brute-force-attack) you can find alot more information about preventing brute forces.

Comment: I know that i can use sessions. But my question is: is is possible to determine how many times a user has failed to log in just with jwt? I could use session only on the log-in page but the session token can be easily deleted from the browser so if the hacker delete the token i can not keep track how many times it is attempting to log in. The ip method  is not that reliable because it can be changed.

Comment: I know that I can use captcha, the IP adress e the session. What I am interested to know is if there is a way to use jwt that allows me to monitor how many times a user tried to log in. For example i could use a jwt token for a failed log in and monitor the log in with that token, but i can be easily deleted.

Comment: I have no experience with jwt, but if it produces a unique token, you could save that token in the database and count the login attempts that way.

Comment: but to check the token you have to read the database every time the hacker send false credential.

Comment: @MarckDuilberg You could do this with a limit. For example after 50 failed login attempts the IP address is banned.